# Python, serial readline, execute one time even if input is multiplied

Tags: python, cycle

I am writing a tool that reads serial /dev/ttyAMA0 (Ninja Pi Crust) from a Raspberry Pi and executes functions when a specific 433Mhz code is received.

So I got this door sensor that sends the code "010111010111011101010000" every time is triggered, I'm able to catch the event and trigger a function that sends me a pushover notification.

Door sensor is sending that signal 4-5 times to make sure the receiver catch the message so my loop executes a few times and here comes the problem, I don't want to receive 4/5 notification every time the door opens so I tried the counter +1 option which works fine but I don't know how to reset the counter after a specific amount of time since I want switch off notification for at least 5 minutes after triggering once.

I tried to flush serial buffer input after first reading, I've also tried to close / reopen serial connection but no luck as it will find again the same code and trigger my function again, any tips ?

```
import serial
from chump import Application
from time import sleep

serialport = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyAMA0',
        baudrate=9600,
        parity=serial.PARITY_ODD,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS,
        timeout=6
)

door = "010111010111011101010000"

def door_open():
        message = user.create_message(
        title='House Notification',
        message="<b>Door Opened</b>",
        html=True
        )
        message.send()
        serialport.close()
        sleep(5)
        serialport.open()

while True:
    command = serialport.readline()
    print str(command) # just debugging
    if door in command:
        serialport.flushInput()
        door_open()
        sleep(10)
```

This is the code that I'm using, just removed pushover api vars.

Comment: Flushing the buffer should work, I think. Perhaps you flush it before the \Pi has sent all the commands? So you flush a few of them, but yo receive a few more laterl. Try to add `sleep(10)` just before `serialport.flushInput()` and see what happens.

Comment: Something just came in my mind, should I perhaps flush output buffer instead of the input one?

Comment: flush all buffers maybe, just for good measure ;) But I think it's input buffer. By the way, have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7266558/pyserial-buffer-wont-flush

Comment: Will try this night and let's see what happens, will update

Comment: Solved, OP edited, thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the source to:

```
def door_open():
    message = user.create_message(
        title='House Notification',
        message="<b>Door Opened</b>",
        html=True
    )
    message.send()
    serialport.flushInput()

while True:
    command = serialport.readline()
    print str(command)
    if door in command:
        sleep(10)
        door_open()
```

Now even if the code is sent 5 times from the transmitter it will only get one and trigger the function.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32922516/2) to the question [Python, serial readline, execute one time even if input is multiplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32922516/python-serial-readline-execute-one-time-even-if-input-is-multiplied) by the OP [deepred](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4513008/deepred) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>